# Incorporating an image as legend for ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, png, legend, gridextra

I have an image that I want to use as a custom legend - a universal legend of 3 plots in one figure combined with grid.arrange:

[image: Custom Legend]

I figure I can load this into R with png or some such package and use grid.arrange to place it next to my graphs. Is it possible to include such images in the package that already contains the functions to make my combined chart, and if so where does one put it and how would you call it from within R code then from it's location within the package. I intend to use this sort of graph with this legend often.

UPDATE:

I've created a folder called 'img' in the root of my Package structure and placed the file inside.

In my R code is the line:
`legend <- readPNG(system.file("img", "rgblegend.png", package="HybRIDS"), TRUE)`
However when build the binary, then install it from local zip file, I go to plot and:

`Error in readPNG(system.file("img", "rgblegend.png", package = "HybRIDS"),  : 
  unable to open`
If I check my library there is no folder 'img'

EDIT:

I've checked a source version of my package - it includes the 'img' folder, however installing from source also fails to put the folder into my directory. So I guess my question now is, why does making a binary package not include the img folder, and why does the source package include it but not install it to my library - what do I do to correct this?

Comment: http://developer.r-project.org/Raster/raster-RFC.html

Comment: and what about the `inst` subfolder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[agstudy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15431566/892313) describes how to reference a file in an installed package without having to know where the package was installed. The other part of the problem is getting the image file into the installed package.

From [the "Package subdirectories" second of Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories), the section of interest is about the `inst` subdirectory:

> The contents of the `inst` subdirectory will be copied recursively to the installation directory. Subdirectories of `inst` should not interfere with those used by R (currently, `R`, `data`, `demo`, `exec`, `libs`, `man`, `help`, `html` and `Meta`, and earlier versions used `latex`, `R-ex`). The copying of the `inst` happens after `src` is built so its `Makefile` can create files to be installed.

So for a file to appear in the `img` directory off the root of the installed package, it must appear in the `inst/img` directory of the source. So move `rgblegend.png` from `img` to `inst/img` and then

```
legend <- readPNG(system.file("img", "rgblegend.png", package="HybRIDS"), TRUE)
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question is how you can be sure to find the image within the package. You can put the png under a folder `img` of your package. and call it using something like this :

```
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Zwrch.png", package=package_name))
```

The complete solution looks to something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)     
library(grid)        ## to create the image grobe
library(png)         ## to read the png
library(gridExtra)   ## to arrange the plots
bp <- ggplot(PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight)) + geom_boxplot()
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Zwrch.png", package=package_name))
legend <- rasterGrob(image=img)
grid.arrange(bp,legend)
```

Comment: Hi yes this is what I'm looking to do, I have tried this, but I get the error saying unable to open. I have created a folder called img in the root of my package, put the image file in and built a windows binary, but it does not seem to work since if I dig into my R library and look in the package 'png' directory I see an img folder, but in my package directory I see no such folder. I am sure I've spelt everything correctly - updating origional question.